# Initial Core Data entities

Tags: core-data

My application is document based and uses Core Data. I want to create some initial entities when a new document is created. I use `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject`, but then the document is considered edited and there is an action that can be undone an redone. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your document's `undoManager` to `nil` (keep a reference to it) before inserting your boilerplate objects, then set it back.